# Getting vertex-shader transformed geometry back from the gpu in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to generate vertex geometry on the cpu and then pass it to the GPU and run a number of vertex shaders on the vertices and then get these transformed vertices back to the cpu. I dont want to render the vertices or run any fragment shaders.

Is it possible to get the vertex-shader transformed vertices back from the gpu onto the cpu?
If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the facility required is called "Transform Feedback Buffers". Extension to OpenGL-2
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/transform_feedback2.txt

Introduced to being official OpenGL functionality with OpenGL-3.0

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. My next question is whether this function exists for OpenGL ES 2.0 for the iPhone? Or if there is some way to do it (doesnt matter how hacky...)

Comment: @twerdster: Two things. 1: This is not a forum. Questions are asked using the "Ask Question" button, not the "add comment" button. 2: No, ES 2.0 can't do transform feedback. You probably should have mentioned ES 2.0 in your original post.

Comment: Note: Transform feedback is a part of OpenGL 3.0. ARB_transform_feedback2 adds to this functionality: state objects to store feedback state, and primitive drawing without querying number of vertices. Useful functionality to be sure, but not something you absolutely *need* to have transform feedback.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I wasn't sure about OpenGL-3 and was too lazy to check ;) changed it.

Comment: umm... feedback buffers cull the z coordinates to -1.0 to 1.0 and give vertices in screen coordinates, and get rid of vertices outside of screen. :\

Comment: @Dmitry: Back then (IIRC) I've read the question as "how to can I get information on how the GPU sees the vertices after passing them through all steps". If you just want to transform the vertices, use a compute shader that performs all the transformation steps without the clipping/culling.